# How to set the back ground brush of a QGraphicsScene with a style sheet

Tags: c++, qt, stylesheet, qgraphicsscene

Is it possible to set the background brush of a QGraphicsScene with a Qt style sheet? I tried

```
QGraphicsScene {
background-color: #f00;
}
```

but it doesn't work. Is it possible to use stylesheets in the Qt Graphics View framework at all?

Comment: Just a thought: have you tried using `#ff0000` instead of `#f00`?

Comment: Both should work. It works with other widgets. It's shorthand for `#ff0000`.

Comment: I know both work in HTML, but I thought you might have discovered that Qt style sheets lacked support for the shorthand version. Seems you didn't, thought. :-)

Comment: We're using the shorthand all the time in Qt style sheets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you instead might be looking for is

```
QGraphicsView {
background-color: #f00;
}
```